# What is MNEB Token?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I've loaded up my Metamask wallet today and was surprised to see it's value at over $50,000.

Almost all of that value was a token that I'd never heard of before and certainly didn't buy. There's a new token in my wallet called MNEB token.

There are 150,000 MNEB tokens valued at $49,997.862 in my Metamask wallet.

Is this a dusting attack? What is this currency and what would happen if I tried to sell it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a cash grab. You have to pay to activate your MNEB transfers and mining. Scam! Value is fake because you can't sell any of the 150k coins.